# Java Reactor: StepVerifier unable to recognize publisher when using as() method

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm trying to do some database operations that talks to MSSQL and MongoDB.  I have my method first insert some data into MSSQL and then into MongoDB.  This is being done as part of a Spring Webflux application.

At the end, I'm doing a database commit via `TransactionalOperator` from Spring Data R2DBC.  The point is to prevent the MSSQL from being committed if data couldn't be written to MongoDB.  If there's a better way to commit on both databases at the end of a function, I'd be interested to know since I'm pretty new to the reactive paradigm.

Here's a test function that I created to demonstrate what I'm essentially doing:

```java
    public Mono<User> doSomeStuff(String username, UUID organization) {
        return userRepo.existsById(oid).flatMap(exists -> {
            if (exists) {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("The user " + username + " already exists!"));
            }

            User newUser = User.builder()
                    .username(username)
                    .organization(organization)
                    .build();

            return userRepo.save(newUser);
        }).flatMap(user -> {
            UserMeta userMeta = UserMeta.builder()
                    .createdOn(new Date())
                    .userId(user.getId())
                    .organization(organization)
                    .build();

            return userMetaRepo.save(userMeta)
                    .thenReturn(user);
        }).as(operator::transactional);
    }
```

When I try to test this function using the following test case:

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Organization wants to add a new user.")
void createUser_returnsOk() {
    UUID orgId = UUID.randomUUID();
    String username = "testuser";

    User testNewUser = User.builder()
            .organization(orgId)
            .username(username)
            .build();

    // Mock following situations
    when(userRepo.existsById(eq(userId))).thenReturn(Mono.just(false));
    when(userRepo.save(eq(testNewUser))).thenReturn(Mono.just(testNewUser));
    when(userMetaRepo.save(any(UserMeta.class)).thenReturn(any(Mono.class));
//        when(operator.transactional(any(Mono.class))).thenReturn(any(Mono.class));

    StepVerifier.create(service.createUser(username, orgId))
            .expectNext(testNewUser)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

I end up getting the following error:

`Cannot invoke "org.reactivestreams.Publisher.subscribe(org.reactivestreams.Subscriber)" because "publisher" is null`

I found out that the function `.as(operator::transactional)` is causing this issue.  It seems that it doesn't return a Mono/Flux, which is causing the `StepVerifier` to being unable to recognize a publisher.

What would be the correct way to deal with publishers that involves doing a transform at the end?

Comment: What happens if you mock `operator::transactional`?

Comment: When mocking `operator::transactional`, I get the error `Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:`. The two are the `userMetaRepo` and the `operator::transactional`

Comment: the `null` aspect of the error is puzzling, and I would investigate further to understand where that `null` comes from. it doesn't sound like "it doesn't recognize a publisher". That said, `Flux#transform` applies the function AND converts to a `Flux` so you might want to try that.

Comment: @JosephWoolf why do you use `Argument matchers ` in thenReturn?:

`when(userMetaRepo.save(any(UserMeta.class)).thenReturn(any(Mono.class));`

Comment: I didn’t really care for an actual object.  I did change it to mock an instance of UserMeta

Comment: According to documentation "Argument matchers" any(Class<T> type) returns null.
[docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-)
If you do not care about result consider changing mocking to:
`when(userMetaRepo.save(any(UserMeta.class)).thenReturn(Mono.empty());`

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. But can't create a new post because people just love to downvote and close the post rather than making a suggestion.